# Assignment expression without direct use

Tags: python-3.x, python-assignment-expression

I'd like to introduce assignment expressions in my code where possible but I've stumbled upon a very simple case I didn't find an example for:

Given a very common example

```
[(y := f(x), x/y) for x in some_iterable]
```

I wonder how to *not* use `y` directly, e.g. I only want `x/y` and `y/x`.

In a more realistic example I would currently write

```
[(obj.elem1, obj.elem2) for x in some_iterable for obj in (f(x),)]
```

which is not very intuitive but the only way I know to mimic a `let` or `where` semamtic.

Is there some way to say

```
[(obj.elem1, obj.elem2) where obj := f(x) for x in some_iterable]
```

?

**Edit**:

One very obvious way would be to write

```
[((obj := f(x)).elem1, obj.elem2) for x in some_iterable]
```

but this is hard to read in my eyes. I'd rather have a way to still write `(obj.elem1, obj.elem2)` and move the assignment out of the tuple.

Comment: Your function could return an iterator. Something like `[(obj.a, obj.b) for obj in my_iter(some_iterable)]`and where `my_iter` looks like `for x in some_iterable: yield f(x)`. Did this help you ?

Comment: My question is more about the assignment expression syntax. So your answer is correct but it's not exactly what I'm looking for